# How to install custom version of maven in azure devops pipleine?

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I have installed adopt openjdk 16 using the task below.

```
steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    wget https://github.com/adoptium/temurin16-binaries/releases/download/jdk-16.0.2%2B7/OpenJDK16U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_16.0.2_7.tar.gz
    pwd
    ls -lRt
  displayName: 'Download jdk'
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: 'OpenJDK16U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_16.0.2_7.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '/opt/jdkcustom'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: true
- script: |
    java -version
    ls -lRt
    pwd
    ls $(Pipeline.Workspace)
```

I download the jdk with step 1 and installed it using step 2 "JavaToolInstaller@0"

I didn't find such for maven, can anyone please suggest.